# Why does TRAMP not work when ssh to a normal user?

Tags: tramp, ssh

## Question

I setup a SSH server on a Gentoo machine.
I copied my identity file (public key) to the server under both the `/root/.ssh` and `/home/i/.ssh` (assuming the username is `i`).
And I edit my `/etc/hosts` to give an alias (assuming its `desktop`) to the server IP.

SSH works perfectly in a terminal:

```
ssh i@desktop # or root@desktop
```

If I type `C-x C-f` in Emacs, and enter the path `/ssh:root@desktop:/`, a `Dired` buffer pops up showing me all directories in `/` on the server.
But when I enter the path `/ssh:i@desktop:/`, Emacs hangs.

## Update

I'm sorry that the debug information was not provided. I set `tramp-verbose` to `6` and get the following logs.

```
14:54:24.705903 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(\(Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no\(?:\(?:/\[fingerprint]\)?)\?\)\)\s-*\)\'" from remote shell
14:54:24.705923 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(\(\(?:Store key in cache\? (y/\|Update cached key\? (y/n, Return cancels connectio\)n)\)\s-*\)\'" from remote shell
14:54:24.705943 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(\(TERM = (.*)\|Terminal type\? \[.*\]\)\s-*\)\'" from remote shell
14:54:24.705962 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(Access granted\. Press Return to begin session\. \)\'" from remote shell
14:54:24.705982 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^
*Confirm user presence for key .*[
]*\)\'" from remote shell
14:54:24.706001 
14:54:24.708144 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
14:54:24.708216 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection nil for idesktop using ssh...failed
14:54:24.708297 tramp-process-sentinel (5) # Sentinel called: ‘#<process *tramp/ssh idesktop*>’ ‘killed: 9
```

It seems to be a shell prompt issue.
I did do some investigation but not noticed this.
Sorry for this dumb question.
Thanks for your kindness.

This link [Tramp hangs #3](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#h5o-9) tells what to do.

Comment: You may want to try the troubleshooting for tramp hanging listed in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#h5o-4 and report your results.

Comment: See also [Bug reporting](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Bug-Reports) and [Traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Traces-and-Profiles) in the Tramp manual. Increase the verbosity level to 6 and check the contents of the `*tramp/foo*` and `* debug tramp/foo*` buffers: they might lead you to the problem. That will also be useful if you decode to send a bug report with `M-x tramp-bug`.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you have a shell prompt not recognized by Tramp. Follow the Tramp manual for investigation. Or follow what @NickD has proposed.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved this by the third item of tramp hangs on the wiki. 

Answer (score 2):

Echoing the comments, it's possible your prompt is confusing tramp (that's usually the case). As a `zsh` user, I have this set *very* early in my `~/.zshrc` on host machines:

```sh
## tramp gets hung up on precmd(), unset some features
if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
    unsetopt zle
    unsetopt prompt_cr
    unsetopt prompt_subst
    unfunction precmd
    unfunction preexec
    PS1='$ '
    return
fi
```

This unsets a a couple of features, sets a simple prompt, and bails out on processing the rest of the file. The options and functions we're un-doing are `zsh` specific. For `bash` you probably only need.

```sh
if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
    PS1='$ '
    return
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. This dose work!